# Changing superclass constructor behavior from subclass

Tags: java

I am currently running into an issue with a plugin I have to develop. The main problem is that I have to work on pre-existing classes, that are not always designed to be worked on .. This involves a lot of workarounds.

To be more specific, here is a sample of code approaching my problem :

```
public class OriginalHerd {
     private Animal baseAnimal;
     public Orignal() { this.baseAnimal = new Animal(); }
}

public class CustomHerd extends OriginalHerd {
     private Dog customAnimal;
     public Custom() { this.customAnimal = new Dog(); }
}
```

Where Dog extends Animal.
Now, let's assume that I don't have access, and can't modify, the OriginalHerd class. And let's also assume that its constructor is a 200 lines monstruosity, where only this line needs to be changed to define my subclass CustomHerd.

```
this.originalAnimal = new Animal();
```

changed by :

```
this.originalAnimal = new Dog();
```

Is there a way to do so without going the Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V road ? Especially because, since baseAnimal isn't protected, I would have to copy pretty much all of OriginalHerd behavior in the child class ...

I sure hope that there is a embarassingly simple solution to this problem, but I can't find it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: no, there's no simple solution.

Comment: This is too bad ... I guess the hard solution is, as I said, to copy all of my original class bahvior in its subclass ? This is pretty ugly but this might work ..

Comment: Parent class was not designed for extension. You can 1) Copy-Paste 2) Do some hacks like classpath replacement

Comment: I'm not sure classpath replacement would work anyway, since to use my example again, Animal would be an internal class of OriginalHerd... Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Other than the options AdamSkywalker said, you can also use reflection to access that _private_ `baseAnimal `, but that will slow your application down.

Comment: Does reflection slow down the application significantly ? I had never heard of that before, that sounds handy

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand what classpath replacement is - you create exact same class (name and package) as that parent class, modify it as you wish, build a jar and put it at the top of classpath, so your class will "hide" thirdparty library class. This can work sometimes.

Comment: Oh I see, indeed I hadn't undestand. This seem a bit overkill in my case, but I'll think about it, thanks

Comment: if you have access to the setter of `originalAnimal ` then you can do something like this in your custom constructor

    `public Custom() { 
        super();
        setCustomAnimal(new Dog());
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Either you have access to the animal's setter, something like:

```
OriginalHerd originalHerd = new OriginalHerd();
originalHerd.setAnimal(new Dog());
```

Or, if animal is private and unaccessible, you can use reflection:

```
OriginalHerd originalHerd = new OriginalHerd();
try {
    Field field = OriginalHerd.class.getDeclaredField("baseAnimal");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(originalHerd, new Dog());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
}
```

Beware though that it may fail at runtime with reflection. What I like to do (when I have to use reflection), I really really make sure it is covered by a unit test, so that it fails at build-time too!